# Extracting src attribute

Tags: python, web-scraping

### What I want to do:

This HTML code:

```html
<img class="poster lazyload lazyloaded"
     data-src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w94_and_h141_bestv2/3qlQM9KP1cyvNfPChA9rASASdHr.jpg"
     data-srcset="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w94_and_h141_bestv2/3qlQM9KP1cyvNfPChA9rASASdHr.jpg 1x, https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w188_and_h282_bestv2/3qlQM9KP1cyvNfPChA9rASASdHr.jpg 2x"
     alt="Hitman"
     src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w94_and_h141_bestv2/3qlQM9KP1cyvNfPChA9rASASdHr.jpg"
     srcset="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w94_and_h141_bestv2/3qlQM9KP1cyvNfPChA9rASASdHr.jpg 1x, https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w188_and_h282_bestv2/3qlQM9KP1cyvNfPChA9rASASdHr.jpg 2x"
     data-loaded="true">
```

I want to extract the "data-src" or "src" (or every attribute contain the URL to the image) attribute value.

### What I Tried:

```
Posters = soup.find("img")["src"]
print(Posters)
```

But this obviously returns all the values from every img tag, so every link is not related to the posters.
Output:

```
https://www.themoviedb.org/assets/2/v4/logos/v2/blue_short-8e7b30f73a4020692ccca9c88bafe5dcb6f8a62a4c6bc55cd9ba82bb2cd95f6c.SVG
https://www.themoviedb.org/assets/2/v4/logos/v2/blue_short-8e7b30f73a4020692ccca9c88bafe5dcb6f8a62a4c6bc55cd9ba82bb2cd95f6c.SVG
```

With posters I mean (check this URL: `https://www.themoviedb.org/search?&query=Hitman`) the posters of films.

### Summary

I want to extract the value inside an attribute, inside the class ".lazyloaded"

I hope is everything clear. Thanks.

---

Edit:

### Explaination, where was the problem?

For everyone reading, Laurent's answer is the solution, the problem was the parsed HTML.

As we can see on my browser the class that contain the attribute that i was trying to scrape was inside the class "poster lazyload lazyloaded":
[image: HTML]

but if we print the website.content:

```html
   <img class="poster lazyload" 
        data-src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w94_and_h141_bestv2/lrDpwvha8VX05vIFxeSZTiPJGYl.jpg"                                                                          
        data-srcset="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w94_and_h141_bestv2/lrDpwvha8VX05vIFxeSZTiPJGYl.jpg 1x, https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w188_and_h282_bestv2/lrDpwvha8VX05vIFxeSZTiPJGYl.jpg 2x"
        alt="The Hitman&#x27;s Bodyguard Collection">
```

it's very very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to filter by `class`:

```py
posters  = soup.find_all("img", {"class": "lazyloaded"})

for poster in posters:
    print(poster["src"])
```

See the documentation: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class

**edit:** more explanation

Say you have the following file `demo.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<img class="logo" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w94_and_h141_bestv2/3qlQM9KP1cyvNfPChA9rASASdHr.jpg">
<img class="poster lazyload lazyloaded"
     data-src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w94_and_h141_bestv2/3qlQM9KP1cyvNfPChA9rASASdHr.jpg"
     data-srcset="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w94_and_h141_bestv2/3qlQM9KP1cyvNfPChA9rASASdHr.jpg 1x, https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w188_and_h282_bestv2/3qlQM9KP1cyvNfPChA9rASASdHr.jpg 2x"
     alt="Hitman"
     src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w94_and_h141_bestv2/3qlQM9KP1cyvNfPChA9rASASdHr.jpg"
     srcset="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w94_and_h141_bestv2/3qlQM9KP1cyvNfPChA9rASASdHr.jpg 1x, https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w188_and_h282_bestv2/3qlQM9KP1cyvNfPChA9rASASdHr.jpg 2x"
     data-loaded="true">
</body>
</html>
```

You can parse the "poster" images like this:

```py
import io

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with io.open("demo.html", encoding="utf8") as fd:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fd.read(), features="html.parser")

posters = soup.find_all("img", {"class": "lazyloaded"})

for poster in posters:
    print(poster["src"])
```

You get:

```
https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w94_and_h141_bestv2/3qlQM9KP1cyvNfPChA9rASASdHr.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks you Laurent, i tried but it's not printing anything, i checked if the class was correct, i'm getting the class with this extension: https://selectorgadget.com/, i will try to see the documentation.

Comment: Update: i printed the website content and the class name it's not the same, it is "poster lazyload", i can't found a "lazyloaded", so i tried poster or lazyload but gives me KeyError

Comment: Update 2.0: Worked, i read better the class and there wasn't the attribute "src", but i saw "data-srcset" and "data-src", i changed the attribute to "data-src" and everything worked. Thanks you a lot Laurent, the problem was the parsed html.